# How to get Eclipse to recognize a .target file for OSGI

Tags: eclipse, file, osgi, target

I moved to a new computer and moved my OSGI project to it. I have a .target file that is now recognized as xml, but in my last setup, I had something installed that made Eclipse interpret it correctly. I can't figure out which thing to install in the install new software section. Does anybody know what I should look for?

Comment: AFAIK ".target" files belong to Plugin Projects - have you imported the project as a Plugin Project?

Comment: Do you have the same version of Eclipse? AFAIR, .target files appeared in 3.6 and later.

Comment: I do have 3.6, curiously enough my friend has 3.4 and recognized .target files right off the bat.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you install the Plugin Development Environment ? (PDE)

Comment: I found a jar file describing itself as the pde core plugin, but I cannot figure out how to install it. I went to help->install new software and tried pointing it at the jar, but it says no software exists. Should I not be looking for jar files to install? Is pde core the correct one?

Comment: Go to help->install new software, choose the update site of your release (Helios, Ganymede, etc) and install the Eclipse Plug-in Developement Environment under General Purpose Tools